# Recursive polynomial family in c

Tags: c, recursion, polynomials

I have a family of polynomial defined recursively:

```
T0(x)=1
T1(x)=2x−1,
Tk(x)=2(2x−1)T(k−1)(x)−T(k−2)(x),∀k= 2,3,...
```

What I have to do is define a function that calculate and store in a matrix the coefficients of the polynomials.

Example:
+1.0000e+00

-1.0000e+00 +2.0000e+00

+1.0000e+00 -8.0000e+00 +8.0000e+00

My attempt is:

```
if(k==0){
    c[0][0]=1.;
}
if(k==1){
    c[0][0]=1.;
    c[1][0]=-1.;
    c[1][1]=2.;
}
if(k>1){ 
    f(k-1,c);
    c[k][k-1]=-2*c[k-1][k-1];
    for(i=0; i<k-1; i++){
        c[k][i]=-(c[k-2][i]+2*c[k-1][i]);
    }
    c[k][k]=0;
    for(i=0; i<k; i++){
        c[k][i+1]+=4*c[k-1][i];
    }
}
```

But I have a segmention fault.What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the size of the array `c`? You might be accessing memory out of bounds.

Comment: c is size of  kxk

Comment: Then valid indices in `c` are 0 to k-1. Accessing `c[k][k]`, for example, is out of bounds, which your code is doing.

Comment: Even though, I defined the array c of size (k+1)x(k+1), I get in valgrind invalid write of size 8, now what's the problem?

Comment: You should add the error message to your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I should be a good thing, if you get a SIGSEGV signal... **to check with a debugger the precise point in the code where you get it**, as the accesses to the data will be closer than if you offer all the code together with no hint.  please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  In your case, as you only post a snippet of code, it's impossible to reproduce the SIGSEGV, but you only allow to guess by inspection.